How can draw the general structure of protein as in attached image?
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart
\chemfig{H_2N-C(-[2]R)(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-OH}
\+
\chemfig{H-N(-[2]H)-C(-[2]\charge{30:-1pt=$\prime$}{R})(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-OH}
\arrow{->}
\chemfig{H_2N-C(-[2]R)(-[6]H)-@{a}C(=[2]O)-@{b}N(-[2]H)-C(-[2]\charge{30:-1pt=$\prime$}{R})(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-OH}
\chemmove{
    \draw[
    fill=purple,
    draw=purple,
    fill opacity=.2,
    rounded corners=2pt
    ]
    ([xshift=-3pt,yshift=-3pt]a.south west)
    rectangle
    ([xshift=4pt,yshift=3pt]b.north east) ;
}
\+
\chemfig{H_2O}
\schemestop
\end{document}


I want to draw the structure using package chemfig, as in bellow attached image.


Can you please elaborate on the specific issue or problem you are facing while using the chemfig package?

If you are looking for some inspiration, the posts under the chemfig tag might be of interest. Also you may see this external blog page: https://genedan.com/no-117-amino-acid-structural-formulas-with-chemfig-non-polar-side-chains/

Please edit to show us what you've tried so we can understand the specific issue you're running into. If the question gets closed, editing will automatically get it reviewed for re-opening.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2.5em}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemfig{H_2N-C(-[2]R)(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-[@{a}]OH}
    \+
    \chemfig{H-[@{b}]N(-[2]H)-C(-[2]R|')(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-O@{ab}H}
    \arrow(.south west--.north west){0}[-90,0.4]
    \chemfig{H_2N-C(-[2]R)(-[6]H)-[@{c}]C(=[2]O)-N(-[2]@{e}H)-[@{d}]C(-[2]R|')(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-OH}
    \+
    \chemfig{H_2@{cd}O}
    \schemestop
    \chemmove{
        \filldraw[draw=cyan, fill=cyan!10, rounded corners=1pt, blend mode=multiply] ([yshift=-2ex]a) rectangle ([yshift=2ex]b);
        \filldraw[draw=cyan, fill=cyan!10, rounded corners=1pt, blend mode=multiply] ([yshift=-2ex]c) rectangle ([yshift=2ex]e -| d);
        \draw[stealth-] ($(c)!0.5!(d)$) ++(0,-2ex) -- ++(0,-4ex)
            node[below,font=\footnotesize] {Amide bond};
        \draw[-stealth] (ab.east) ++(2ex,0) -- ++(1em,0) |- ([xshift=2ex]cd.east);
    }
\end{document}



Thanks that's great.

After writing the first two structures, the third is simply the combination of the first two, minus the water.
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
        \chemfig{H_2N-C(-[2]R)(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-OH}
        \+
        \chemfig{H-N(-[2]H)-C(-[2]\charge{30:-1pt=$\prime$}{R})(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-OH}
        \arrow{->}
        \chemfig{H_2N-C(-[2]R)(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-N(-[2]H)-C(-[2]\charge{30:-1pt=$\prime$}{R})(-[6]H)-C(=[2]O)-OH}
        \+
        \chemfig{H_2O}
    \schemestop
\end{document} 


